# Ember.js Navigation Controller - am I on the right path?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm currently building a reporting platform for internal use and decided to use Ember.js.  So far it's been both a good and bad experience; the bad is mostly related to the documentation and how most things I've researched online have changed with the latest revisions of ember.

We are using twitter bootstrap and the navigation portion of bootstrap has the `active` class on the `li` element instead of the `a` element. Naturally my first inclination was to just use jquery as a hack and just change the active class manually which felt totally wrong and decided to find the 'right' way.

So I ended up building a custom view for the navigation, see below: (note: I am using browserify)

```js
// NavigationView.js
module.exports = Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'navbar',

    // Bind the 'selected' property on this view to the controllers 'selected' property.
    selectedBinding: 'AnalyticsApp.NavigationController.selected',

    // a single sub item for the nav
    NavViewElement: Ember.View.extend({

      // Change the tag name to be a LI tag since bootstrap requires active class
      // to exist on that, instead of the default (ember) anchor tag when using {{linkTo}}
      tagName: 'li',

      // Bind the 'active' class to the computed property; checking if this nav
      // element is the current active tab.
      classNameBindings: ['isActive:active'],

      // This computed property will check if this nav item is active
      isActive: function() {
          return this.get('item') === this.get('parentView.selected');
      }.property('item', 'parentView.selected')

   })
});
```

Now, setting up the view was pretty straight forward, to use it to render a nav element I can use this:

```html
{{#view view.NavViewElement item="network" }}
    {{#linkTo 'network'}}
        <i class="icon-sitemap"></i>
        <span>Networks</span>
    {{/linkTo}}
{{/view}}
```

In all the routes in the `setupController` method I am setting the 'selected' tab like so

```js
AnalyticsApp.NavigationController.set('selected', 'network');
```

Now here is where I am unsure regarding my implementation and I would really appreciate if someone could tell me if I'm way off target or if I am on the right path.

I am using the `NavigationController` (below) to be the central store for the navigation logic, it is actually an `ObjectController` that I've extended and chained `.create()` on.

```js
AnalyticsApp.NavigationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  selected: null
}).create();
```

I tried extending a standard controller, but that doesn't expose the set / get methods.  Is using an `ObjectController` for this type of setup the right type?

Thanks for taking the time to read, and I appreciate any and all feedback.

-Ryan S.

Comment: Since your `NavigationController` is used app wide, have tried just creating the controller like so `AnalyticsApp.NavigationController = Ember.ObjectController.create({selected:null});`? Does it then expose the `set` & `get` methods?

Comment: Yep, that does actually work, thanks!  Wasn't aware I could just run create without extending.

Comment: There is a difference dough, if you use `extend` on the controller all instances that will be created will have the `selected` property on it, with `create` just the instance you are creating.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but how did your NavigationController become aware of changes to the selection as to update the selected property?

Comment: @d2kagw each route in the application that needs to update the nav has a `setupController` function that I'm setting the selected tab within: `AnalyticsApp.NavigationController.set('selected', 'index');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since my comment was usefull, I'll convert it to an answer. So, since your `NavigationController` is used app wide, try just to create the controller like so:

```
AnalyticsApp.NavigationController = Ember.ObjectController.create({selected:null});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, appreciate it.